# Login Required Django Classed Based View

Tags: django, templates, url, authentication, required

Totally beginner question.

I have this view in my app Foo:

```
class PaymentsView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):

    login_url = '/login/'
    redirect_field_name = 'redirect_to'

    # -- Omitted ...
```

I have read the django documentation but I didn't see where to put my file "login.html" and how can I set the url for that. When I run the code show the 404 error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting `login_url` will redirect to a URL within your project, which is then handled by URL Dispatcher. You'll need to include a path to that URL within your URLConf, just like you would with any other URL:

urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('login/', views.login),
]
```

You'll then need to write a view to handle the login. Django provides pre-written views and URL patterns that handle this with its [login system](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/default/).

Comment: Thx I got what you mean, I was totally lost.